# Prove about Expected Value of a Random Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Show that (A X) = A (X) if A is a non-random m×n matrix and X is random n×k matrix.
￼How can I show the proof?

Comment: Try thinking about the definition of a product of matrices (involving a summation) and remembering the expectation is linear.

Answer (score 1):

By representing matrix $\bf A$ as a block of its members, $[A_{i,j}]_{m\times n}$ we have:

$$\begin{align} \\ \mathsf E(\mathbf A~\mathbf X) ~=~& \mathsf E([A_{i,j}]_{m\times n}~[X_{j,k}]_{n\times k}) \\ ~=~& ~ & \textsf{matrix multiplication} \\ =~& ~ & \textsf{linearity of expectation} \\ =~& ~ & \textsf{extract constants from expectation}\\=~& ~ & \textsf{matrix multiplication} \\=~& \mathbf A~\mathsf E(\mathbf X) \end{align}$$

Fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{A} = [A_{ij}]_{m \times n}$ and $E(\mathbf{X}) = E([X_{ij}]_{n \times k}) = [E(X_{ij})]_{n \times k} = [\mu_{ij}]_{n \times k}$,

$E(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X})$

$= E\left(\left[\sum\limits_{z = 1}^n A_{iz} X_{zj} \right]_{m \times k} \right)$

$= \left[E\left(\sum\limits_{z = 1}^n A_{iz} X_{zj} \right) \right]_{m \times k}$

$= \left[\sum\limits_{z = 1}^n A_{iz} \mu_{zj} \right]_{m \times k}$

$= \mathbf{A}E(\mathbf{X})$